# How to use MVC3 client-side form validation in an Ajax form?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

The whole thing is, that I want to be able to use MVC3's built in client side validations, on my custom written Ajax codes. (I'm talking about the validations which are available in the forms made using both `HTML.BeginForm()` & `Ajax.BeginForm()`)

My model looks like this :

```
public class BrandVewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Brand Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in the blank!")]
        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "The name must not be more than 40 characters long!")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And my View looks like this :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Insert_Brand", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)

    <input value="Create"  type="submit" name="Create New Brand"  />

    <div id="result"></div>
}
```

As you can see, I'm using `Ajax.BeginForm()` which is good. Obviously and regarding to my viewmodel if the user leaves the Name field blank and clicks the submit button, they will be shown the corresponding error, WITHOUT having the form data sent to the server ! (since it's client-side, form validation, thanks to jQuery)

But I need to have my simple form as seen below, (instead of an `Ajax.BeginForm()`) AND have all the client-side validation features:

```
<form method="post" action="@Html.Action("Insert_Brand","Admin")">

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)

    <a onclick="CreateBrand()">Create Brand</a>

</form>

//    honestly I have no idea what 'custom-written ajax coding', or what I do here is called :p 

    <script type="text/javascript" >
            function CreateBrand() {
                var item = { Brand: { Name:$('#Name').val()} };
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Admin/Insert_Brand',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(item),
                    dataType: "text json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (t) {
                        console.log(t);
                        $("#result").html(t);
                        return;
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log("Failed!");
                        console.log("XMLHttpRequest=" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + "\ntextStatus=" + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown=" + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

As I said, I need to have all the good validation messages, shown to user, when I use THIS kind of ajax form posting. but I don't know how I could achieve that...

Is there any way?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, what problems are you currently facing and how does the code that you have shown relates to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why client side validation isn't working in your case is because you have hardcoded the `<form>` tag and thus there's nothing to instantiate the `FormContext`. And without a FormContext, HTML helpers such as `TextBoxFor` do not emit any HTML5 data-* validation attributes that are used by the unobtrusive framework.

So simply use the `Html.BeginForm` helper:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert_Brand", "Admin"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)

    <a onclick="CreateBrand()">Create Brand</a>
}
```

But instead of subscribing to the onclick event of the anchor I would recommend you to use a submit button and subscribe to the `.submit()` event. The reason for this is because while the focus is inside the textbox the user could press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> on his keyboard to submit the form and then the form will submit with a normal request. Your AJAX handler will never run.

So:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert_Brand", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)

    <button type="submit">Create Brand</button>
}
```

and then in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function() {

        var item = { Brand: { Name: $('#Name').val() } };
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: JSON.stringify(item),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (t) {
                console.log(t);
                $('#result').html(t);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Failed!");
                console.log("XMLHttpRequest=" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + "\ntextStatus=" + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown=" + errorThrown);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

But if for some cryptic reason you insist on hardcoding manually this `<form>` tag instead of using the helpers that are designed for this purpose, you could also manually create the FormContext by adding the following line to the top of your view:

```
@{
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}
```

and thus tricking the Html helpers into believing that they are inside a form and force them to emit the HTML5 data-* validation attributes.

Comment: Thanks A LOT Darin Dimitrov :)
I'll give it a try and tell you the result.